# How to click on radio button in Angular JS application using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate an Angular application with Python Selenium but I'm having trouble locating certain elements. The HTML below is a radio button I'm trying to select

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="$ctrl.selectedItem" ng-value="item" ng-click="$ctrl.onItemChange(item)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" name="1944" value="[object Object]" aria-invalid="false" style="">
```

I've been using WebDriverWait with expected conditions in the form of:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@ng-model='$ctrl.selectedItem']")))
```

I've tried using this with the class name and the name as well, but I keep getting either the nosuchelement exception or the timeoutexception listed below:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@ng-model='$ctrl.selectedItem']")))
  File "C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

So I'm obviously not locating the element correctly as its timing out, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you go to your webpage and search for your xpath, do you find the element in the browser dev tool?

Comment: Secondly, if you just do driver.find_element statement, in all your tried xpaths, does it returns element not found exception, or the exception differs?

Comment: @JakyRuby I can see the element in my dev tools when I inspect it

Comment: @KumarRishabh the exception always remains the same

Comment: Here exception will always be same.. I am interested in knowing that what error does the driver.find_element is throwing and not the exception I am getting from the dynamic wait.

Comment: I have actually solved this now. The radio button was hidden behind a dropdown menu and I didn't realize that I had to activate that dropdown first. Thank you both for taking the time to look at my question